# Syncing Nickname and "Display name publicly as" by default

Tags: functions, user-meta

I have a form that allows people to update their `display_name`.
However, this doesn't work. I'm using Bricks Builder with Bricksforge but none of their own platforms seem to get the right answer.
So what I'm doing is the following:

1. I prefill the form field with the `{wp_user_display_name}`
2. Then I use Brickforge's "update user meta" to update the `nickname` meta key. This does update it in the backend!
3. Now I want the `nickname` to synchronize automatically to the "Display name publicly as" field, but this is where the trouble starts as this field is not auto updating whenever I save the form.

Any ideas on how to fix this or sync the 2 fields?
Huge thanks in advance as I've been struggling with this for over 5 hours now.